# Counting TOP 4 rows from SQL after the first TOP 4 rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I want to display the records which occur in row number 5, 6, 7 and 8 (4 results) excluding the TOP 4 in descending order. Currently I tried using `SELECT * FROM estate_ad_listing WHERE eal_id != TOP (4) ORDER BY eal_id DESC LIMIT 4` but I am getting error. I am using PDO. Please help.

My query:

```
$sal = "SELECT * FROM estate_ad_listing WHERE eal_id != TOP (4) ORDER BY eal_id DESC LIMIT 4";
$wur = $PDO->prepare($sal);
$wur -> execute();
```

Comment: Use the offset of `limit`

Comment: give me an example with my query

Comment: Can you post the what error is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use below query-

```
SELECT * FROM estate_ad_listing ORDER BY eal_id DESC LIMIT 4,4;
```

Note: starting from 5th row and fetching next 4 rows.

Comment: No.. it should be SELECT * FROM estate_ad_listing ORDER BY eal_id DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4;

Comment: if you simply use limit 4,4 means you are saying that start from 5th row (0,1,2,3,4) and fetch next 4 rows. Are you not getting desired results by given query..

Comment: means first parameter is offset and 2nd parameter is row count.